# How to fixed this issue. CSS

Tags: css

> Please see my codes below:

```css
.spl-user-chatbox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    background-color: #2196f3;
    top: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.spl-chatbox-hrd {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    top: 105px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    border-radius: inherit;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 12px -4px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
}
```

```html
<div class="spl-user-chatbox">
                        <div class="spl-chatbox-hrd">
                            <div class="spl-chatbox-close"></div>
                            <div class="spl-chatbox-hrd-uName">Text</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[image]

> Hi, guys just asking how can I remove the color blue on the bottom
> part. I'm so confused why still the color showing even I've added a
> white background in the first place. Can anyone help me with this?
> Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try with background-color:transparent

Comment: But If I tried using transparent. The color blue will not exist, right? I just need it there.

Comment: Can you explain your goal better?

Comment: I just need to remove that color blue on the bottom part. Anyway thanks for chatting about this really appreciate it

Comment: I think you can put a div between the blue part and the text with a padding and a background-color:transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the width and hight to bigger values

```css
.spl-user-chatbox {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #2196f3;
    top: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.spl-chatbox-hrd {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    top: 105px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    min-height: 200%;
    z-index: 1;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    border-radius: inherit;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 12px -4px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
}
```

```html
<div class="spl-user-chatbox">
                        <div class="spl-chatbox-hrd">
                            <div class="spl-chatbox-close"></div>
                            <div class="spl-chatbox-hrd-uName">Text</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to see the `border-radius` at the bottom two corners, just remove those two and only add a `border-radius` to the top two corners.

Add `border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;` to the `.spl-user-chatbox`

```css
.spl-user-chatbox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    background-color: #2196f3;
    top: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px; /* only add border-radius to the top two corners */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.spl-chatbox-hrd {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    top: 105px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    border-radius: inherit;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 12px -4px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
}
```

```html
<div class="spl-user-chatbox">
    <div class="spl-chatbox-hrd">
        <div class="spl-chatbox-close"></div>
        <div class="spl-chatbox-hrd-uName">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've also tried this but still getting the same problem. BTW thanks for sharing your thoughts :)

Comment: @CoreTM Really? I had the same problem you had, but by adding border-radius only to the two top corners, it was solved. I saw it the same as on the image you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that :

```css
    .spl-user-chatbox {
        position: absolute;
        width: 220px;
        height: 220px;
        background-color: #2196f3;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .spl-chatbox-hrd {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        top: 105px;
        left: -1px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        width: calc(100% + 2px);
        min-height: calc(100% + 2px);
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="spl-user-chatbox">
    <div class="spl-chatbox-hrd">
        <div class="spl-chatbox-close"></div>
        <div class="spl-chatbox-hrd-uName">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to only occur when the user zooms the page in the browser. I don't think you can avoid this without adding a white 1px border to the white element, it seems to be a browser quirk. As long as there is no zooming going on, nobody will notice.

Comment: I've also tried this but still the same. I also check on zooming in and still got the background.